# ModuleNotFoundError , while using cv2 package in pyhton

Tags: python, opencv

I've installed opencv-python package also pyhton is updated.
but when I am working with in package it is showing "ModuleNotFoundError"

```
line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I tried to use opencv-pyhton to build a Face recognition app , but due to this error I am not able to even start

Comment: _I've installed opencv-python package_ Show us the exact command you used to install it.

Comment: Its common to have multiple python's where an install in one is not seen in another. Perhaps you did a platform install but you are using an IDE with its own python.

Comment: Please note that when you update the version of Python, you have to re-install all of your packages.

Comment: used pip install opencv-python cmd to install opencv 
following a tutorial to learn opencv the command was mentioned in there..

Comment: Yes, but if you are using an IDE, like PyCharm or VSCode, they often have their own separate installations of Python built-in.

Comment: Please update the question and include the output of this command `pip show opencv-python` and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`